# phone number validation with different first letters

Tags: html

I'm trying to validate hungarian phone numbers which are a little bit harder than other nubmers because we accept 2 types of them:
examples:

```
+36201234567
+36301234567
+36701234567
```

but these ones are also valid:

```
06201234567
06301234567
06701234567
```

I checked the overflow questions already but couldn't find any solution for the first letter if I can accept '+' and '0' aswell.
This is my code which only accepts the '+' format atm.

```
<input type="tel" pattern='[\+](36)(20|30|70)\d{7}' class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="+36301234567" required="required">
```

Comment: `^(\+3|0)`...?!

Comment: Best practice, remove all chars that are not numbers, validate that and show the number the way you want it

Comment: The international preselection-number of hungary is +36 or 0036.

This said your 2nd example is:
0201234567

And your 3rd should be:
0036201234567

By the way: That's international and everywhere the same - nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this regex: `((?:\+?3|0)6)(?:-|\()?(\d{1,2})(?:-|\))?(\d{3})-?(\d{3,4})`. It accepts all kinds of Hungarian phone numbers.

```
<input type="tel" pattern='((?:\+?3|0)6)(?:-|\()?(\d{1,2})(?:-|\))?(\d{3})-?(\d{3,4})' class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="+36301234567" required="required">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd need 20-30-70 after +36. example: +36-30-1234567 and also after 06 example: 06-20-1234567

Comment: @MowerQQ, please mention this in your question

Answer (score 1):

You can make another comination using | like this:

```
pattern="([\+](36)(20|30|70)\d{7})|((06)\d{9})"
```

And also as @grumpy said the best practice is to remove all chars that are not numbers
You can also add a JS function like this with onkeypress events like this `onkeypress="return Validate(event)"`

```
`function Validate(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9+]");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
     if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works fine. But how can I remove chars that are not numbers except '+' ?

Comment: You can change the type of the input to number like this `type="number"` 
The type number accept all numbers, + and -
And the best practice is to make a JS function

Comment: I've edited the answer and I've add the JS function hope that helps you

Comment: Thank you, jus tested it and everything works fine. Accepted it.